Issue with IRFZ44NPBF MOSFETs Not Switching in Battery Management Circuit
I’m designing a battery management circuit to switch a set of Li-ion batteries between parallel and series configurations. For this, I’m using six IRFZ44NPBF MOSFETs controlled by half-bridge drivers (IR2104STRPBF).


Problem:
The first MOSFET switches as expected, but the other two are not responding.
Details:
MOSFETs Used: IRFZ44NPBF
Drivers Used: IR2104STRPBF
Configuration: Switching between parallel and series configurations for Li-ion batteries
Observations: The first MOSFET switches on, but the other two do not respond.
What I’ve Tried:

Verified the gate signals from the half-bridge drivers.
Checked all wiring and connections for any loose or incorrect
connections.
Ensured that the power supply to both the drivers and MOSFETs is
stable and within the required range.

Questions:

What could be causing the other two MOSFETs not to switch?
Are there any specific troubleshooting steps I should follow to
diagnose this issue?
Could there be an issue with the half-bridge drivers or their control signals?


The high side drivers rely on charging the bootstrap capacitors.  Are you turning on the low side FETs often enough to keep the bootstrap cap charged?
